# MySQLi insert not working - Die error

Tags: php, insert

I'm working on a domain shortening service called "sHTTP". It uses a MySQL database to store the shortened URLs. I can't insert them though.

Here's my code:

```
function db(){
    $link = mysqli_connect('sqlserver', 'user', 'pass', 'db') or die(mysqli_error());
    return $link;
}

$url = mysqli_real_escape_string(db(), $_POST['url']);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
function checkexists($name){
    // check if shttp exists
    $q = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query(db(),"SELECT name FROM shttp WHERE name = '$name'"));

    if($q > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}


function generateRandStr($length){
    // generate string for placeholder name
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }

        return $randomString;
    }


    if(checkexists($name)){
        die('sHTTP name exists already!');
        }


    if($_POST['url'] == ''){
        die('No URL entered!');
      }


    if(!$_POST['name']){
        $name = generateRandStr(5);
    }else{
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string(db(), $_POST['name']);
}

//THIS IS MY MAIN PROBLEM HERE GUISE
    $query = "INSERT INTO shttp(name, url, ip) VALUES ($name, $url, $ip)";

//Y U NO WORKING
    $exe = mysqli_query(db(), "INSERT INTO shttp (name, url, ip) VALUES ($name, $url, $ip)");

if(!$exe){
//I'M GETTING THE DIE HALP
    die('Error: Could not be processed');
    } else {
    echo 'sHTTP created!<br>URL: <a href=http://shttp.tk/    '.$name.'>http://shttp.tk/'.$name.'</a>';
    }
```

I'm getting the "Error: Could not be processed" I set up.

Also, my DB table is this:
name varchar(255)
url varchar(255)
ip varchar(255)

I believe that's how I set it up in my code as well.

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Each n every time you are doing the `mysqli_connect('sqlserver', 'user', 'pass', 'db')` ??

Comment: Just as an FYI, your code is quite difficult to read where you have code spaced out in between function definitions, if you keep all your function definitions together in one area of the file, or even better in an included file, and the executable code together it makes it much easier to read and see what is happening.

Comment: Yeah, I typed it up very quickly, it's midnight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use quote for the string values as

```
$query = "INSERT INTO shttp(name, url, ip) VALUES ('$name', '$url', '$ip')" ;
```